# urllib.requests or urllib.request

Tags: python, html, shell

under "urlib" library whether we have **'requests'** module or **'request'** module

When running the below code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print (bsObj.h1)
```

shell is throwing the warning

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 181
    markup_type=markup_type))
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
The code that caused this warning is on line 1 of the file <string>. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:
 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})
to this:
 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser")**

<h1>An Interesting Title</h1>
```

when i do this

```
>>>import requests
```

which shell successfully imports the requests module

but when I change the above code to

```
from urllib.requests import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print (bsObj.h1)
```

shell throws the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\scrapetest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.requests import urlopen
ImportError: No module named 'urllib.requests'
```

and pip tool installs both the modules **(request, requests)** successfully

```
C:Python34\Scripts>pip install request
Requirement already satisfied <use --upgrade to upgrade>: request in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
cleaning up...


C:Python34\Scripts>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied <use --upgrade to upgrade>: requests in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

`urllib` is a module one it own, same thing for `requests`. 
you do :

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

It's `urllib.request` not `urllib.requests` and it explains the error the python interpreter is giving you. 
Here's the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) for `urllib`

As for the first shell error you're getting, python is already giving you a hint as how to solve it.
So, instead of :

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
```

You should do this :

```
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser")
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `requests` module, this is not a built-in module but a third party library.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html").text
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print (bsObj.h1)
```

By the way that warning you have has nothing to do with `request(s)` library, but it is with the `BeautifulSoup` parser.

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time for me.